# Error in Jenkins while fetching projects from github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am a beginner in jenkins. I have configured all the environment variables for Jenkins . I have got a error in integrating a sample Spring maven project from github. I have mentioned the error below.

```
Cloning repository 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\maven Example\workspace # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/mkyong/spring3-mvc-maven-xml-hello-world.git/
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe --version # timeout=10
[WARNING] Installed git version too old for credentials support
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe config --local credential.username viki19nesh@gmail.com # timeout=10
```

Thanks in advance for your responses. [Project configuration in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixnjo.png)

Comment: "Installed git version too old for credentials support" would suggest that you need a later version of git in order to use credentials. Are you using the latest version of git?

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version of git - git version 2.8.1.windows.1 @DanielBarbarian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning message [suggests](https://gitlab.com/MarkEWaite/git-client-plugin/commit/7667ecd49e9da9db3e9385826bad56ee851adacb) that you are running unsupported `git` version. Please check it from `cmd` on the node where job runs. 
If that won't help you,  switch to `JGit` in Jenkins configuration.

Also keep up to date installed Jenkins plug-ins.